# Eclipse not closing previous build CPU usage 100%

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am using Eclipse for C/C++ development. I am trying to compile and run a project. When I compile and run the project after a while my CPU gets to 100% usage . I checked "Task Manager" and there I found that Eclipse isn't closing any of the previous build and it's running in the background which uses my CPU heavily. How do I solve this problem. When at 100% usage my PC becomes very very slow.

Comment: Why would you *not* want to use 100% CPU while compiling? Don't you want it to get done as fast as possible?

Comment: I dont mind using it unless it feels like my PC will crash like any minute. By 100% usage I didnt mean that I dont want it to use 100% rather I dont think it should. And the reason it even used 100% because there were multiple builds of the same project running in the background at least that what Task Manager said. and when I closed those my pc was back to normal. But this keeps happening . Eclipse should automatically close the previous build but its not . And I dont know why.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the build to use up all your CPU time (maybe because you want to do other stuff while building) then you could decrease the parallelism of the build to a point where it leaves one or more cores unused. For example, if you have 8 cores you could configure your build to only use 6 of them.

Your build will take longer, but your machine will be more responsive for other tasks while the build runs.

Comment: I  will try to describe my problem a little further since I dont think the solution you gave me is the correct one. My PC is Windows 7 x64, 6100-FX AMD , 8gb RAM . The program I am running is Priority Queue which is like 200 line episode. So,I dont think its possible to get 100% usage from running only 200 line program.        -------- This is exactly what happened After I build and run the program to debug a couple of time I noticed that my CPU gone to 100% usage. Then in task manager I saw that there were 6-7 PriorityQueue running when I closed them It was back to normal usage.

Answer (score 0):

Adding More RAM seems to have solved my problem. Disk usage is also low now. Maybe Since there wasnt enough RAM in my laptop the CPU was fetching data from the Disk directly which made the disk usage to go up.